# Erro ao instalar pacote ffvideo python

Tags: python

Estou trabalhando com Raspberry Pi com o sistema Raspbian.
Preciso instalar o pacote ffvideo, mas quando eu tento instalá-lo, recebo isto:

```
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/tmp/pip-build-y9gXBT/ffvideo/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-SMHZg9-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-y9gXBT/ffvideo
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.logk
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isto?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que esse erro é comum quando o pacote python-dev não se encontra instalado ou com a versão correta.

Caso a tua versão do raspbian seja o jessie, experimenta instalar o seguinte na linha de comandos:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -t jessie python-dev
```

Caso não seja, experimenta substituir "jessie" pela versão correspondente.